# Proper way to handle null value for Oracle Date datatype in prepared statement

Tags: java, oracle, date, null, prepared-statement

I have a database with more than 20 columns and some of them are `date`/`timestamp` data types with null values.

Java application will read the data from this table and insert into other table. Prepared Statement is used to frame insert query. When inserting the record, I get *"null pointer exception"* on date columns where ever it is null. For the `Varchar`, it is automatically setting to null when the actual value is null. Is there any way to handle the Date fields with null values automatically as like `varchar` in prepared statements?

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
....
....
ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime())); //date is Java.Util.Date
```

Getting Error. So I handle manually like below

```
if(date!= null)
    ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
else
    ps.setNull(3, Types.DATE);
```

Comment: *"Java application will read the data from this table and insert into other table."* Then why do you need to create a new `java.sql.Date`? Isn't `date` already a `java.sql.Date` (or `null`)?

Comment: "I get null pointer expcetion on date columns" - without seeing the DDL for your tables it's impossible to be certain, but it seems likely that the columns you're having trouble with have a NOT NULL constraint on them, meaning that they cannot be set to NULL. Please edit your question to include the DDL for the table, including all columns and constraints, and the exact text of the errors you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: `java.sql.Date` as well as `java.sql.Date` is outdated. These days use `LocalDate` from [java.time, thie modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead: `ps.setObject(3, yourLocalDate);`. Note: (1) use `setObject` insteda of `setDate`. (2) It works when `yourLocalDate` is `null` too.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the source table is in the type of Timestamp and the target table is having datatype as Date. it does not require any time portion.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks. There is no constraint on both source and target table to be not null. the data type of source is Timestamp (allowed null) and the target table datatype is Date(allowed null).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thats great suggestion. and have idea about LocalDate and will try that. But I am curious about exploring any default way to handle Date in prepared statement.

Comment: My bad - I read "null pointer exception" as "not null exception".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, of course, is that you're trying to call `getTime` on `date`, which may be `null`.

> Java application will read the data from this table and insert into other table.

If that's true, then I'd expect `date` to *already* be a `java.sql.Date` (or `null`) and you could just use it directly:

```
ps.setDate(3, date);
```

If `date` is really not a `java.sql.Date`, then you can use the conditional operator:

```
ps.setDate(3, date == null ? null : new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

It's fine to pass `null` into `setDate` (for the same reason it works in `setString`). You only need `setNull` when the Java type you'd use with the column is a primitive type (like `int`). Since you can't call `setInt` with `null` where the `int` should be, you'd use `setNull` in that situation. That's not an issue for `setDate`, though.